# How to very efficiently assign lat/long to city boundary described by shape?

Tags: gis, spatial, shapefile

I have a huge shapefile of 36.000 non-overlapping polygones (city boundaries). I want to easily determine the polygone into which a given lat/long falls. What would the best way given that it must be extremely computationaly efficient ?

I was thinking of creating a lookup table (tilex,tiley,polygone_id) where tilex and tiley are tile identifiers at zoom levels 21 or 22. Yes, the lack of precision of using tile numbers and a planar projection is acceptable in my application.

I would rather not use postgres's GIS extension and am fine with a program that will run for 2 days to generate all the INSERT statements.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Insert statements into what? Are you using a different spatial database or some other database? If you are willing to use python, C, or Java you could use shapely, GEOS, or JTS to write some custom code to do what you want rather simply.

In python use this lib to open the shapefile
http://indiemaps.com/blog/2008/03/easy-shapefile-loading-in-python/

then shapely
http://gispython.org/shapely/docs/1.0/manual.html#contains
to test containment

For Java use Geotools which also includes JTS.

Comment: JTS is what I was looking for along with its ability to do 'point-in-polygone'

Comment: Revisiting this much later... after much trial, error and solutions, we ended up going with postgres/postgis which allows loading a shapefile into the database and doing all sorts of neat things. We're running it on a 16 core machine at 100% utilization.

Comment: Yup - it is a great solution that gets you past the writing all the code yourself. Be sure to think about moving to PostGIS 2.0 - a lot of improvements in there.

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like you want a [BSP tree](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/BSP_tree). Basically you divide the area into smaller and smaller polygons in a tree like fashion.

The advantage is that you don't need to compare coordinates with every polygon later on. That makes it a very fast way to find the correct polygon.